# How to input 64-bit hex values in octave

Tags: 64-bit, octave, hexadecimal

I'm trying to use Octave as a programmer's calculator.  I want to input a 64-bit pointer, but when I do apparently the 64-bit value gets silently truncated to 32-bit:

```
octave:44> base_ptr=0x1010101020202020
base_ptr =  538976288
octave:45> uint64(base_ptr)
ans = 538976288
octave:46> printf("%lx\n", base_ptr)
20202020
```

So it seems like it's truncated the input value to the low 32-bits.  I would use scanf, but the docs say it should only be used internally.

How can I input the full 64-bit value?

Alternately, is there some awesome free programmer's calculator out there for Windows?  (I know Windows calculator has a programmer's mode but I would like arbitrary variable support).  I tried using my ti-89 but it also doesn't support 64-bit hex.

Comment: Depends on exactly what you're looking for in a "programmer's calculator", but `python` works fine for me on arbitrarily large values. The stock Windows 7 calculator isn't all that bad either.

Comment: So, I like your suggestion a lot better - it 'just works', apparently, even beyond 64-bit values.

Comment: Also, I did figure out how to do this in Octave, but its a pain - you have to do hex2dec("0xa0a0b0b0c0c0d0d0") or whatever value you want - for whatever reason this can read in the string correctly.